# How can I count events happened where interval between events within 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like

`--------------------------
ID |  Event | User | Time 
1  |   Buy  | Jack | 12:00
2  | Return | Jack | 12:01
3  |   Buy  | John | 12:01
4  |   Buy  | Jack | 12:07
5  | Return | John | 12:07
6  | Return | John | 12:08
---------------------------`

I want to group events by 5 minutes interval to be like

`--------------------------------
User |  CountEvent | From |  To
Jack |       2     | 12:00| 12:01
John |       1     | 12:01| 12:01
Jack |       1     | 12:07| 12:07
John |       2     | 12:07| 12:08
--------------------------------`

I tried

```
select User,Count(Event),Min(Time),Max(Time) 
from User_Events 
group by (4 * HOUR(Time) + FLOOR( MINUTE(Time) / 5));`
```

But it gives me wrong results. 
also I tried

```
select User,Count(Event),Min(Time),Max(Time) 
from User_Events 
group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(TransactionTime,INTERVAL 2 Hour)) DIV 300;`
```

Comment: I'm confused by you desired result set. It doesn't look like like it is reflects 5 minute intervals.

Comment: The crude but effective would be a series of COUNT(IF( statements for every 5 minute period - ... where Time between 12:00 and 12:05, 12:06 and 12:10...

Comment: @KarlKieninger i want to count events done by user within 5 minutes together

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not sure I am answering the right question as my output is different than yours, but I do think my output is "correct" as I understand it. Or failing that it may be enough to get to solve it the rest of the way.

```
CREATE TABLE Events (ID INT,  Evnt VARCHAR(10),  Usr VARCHAR(10), Tm TIME);
INSERT INTO Events SELECT 1,'Buy','Jack','12:00';
INSERT INTO Events SELECT 2,'Return','Jack','12:01';
INSERT INTO Events SELECT 3,'Buy','John','12:01';
INSERT INTO Events SELECT 4,'Buy','Jack','12:07';
INSERT INTO Events SELECT 5,'Return','John','12:07';
INSERT INTO Events SELECT 6,'Return','John','12:08';

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.tm,'%H:%i') 'User'
      ,COUNT(1) CountEvents
      ,DATE_FORMAT(a.tm,'%H:%i') 'From'
      ,DATE_FORMAT(MAX(b.tm),'%H:%i') 'To'
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tm FROM Events) a
  JOIN Events b ON b.tm >= a.tm 
               AND b.tm <= ADDDATE(a.tm, INTERVAl 5 MINUTE)
 GROUP BY a.tm
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb20f/13)

Result:

```
User    CountEvents From    To
12:00   3           12:00   12:01
12:01   2           12:01   12:01
12:07   3           12:07   12:08
12:08   1           12:08   12:08
```